# Update statement on a cte with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that basically filters data based on certain criteria, the thing is that after filtering I need to update these records to "correct" them but I get a `4104` on the `UPDATE` statement.

When I call directly the variable I don't have problems but where I do a calculation I get an error because I'm calling the variables from the first and second query.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestmp ASC) order,
    *
    FROM TSTSOLAP T
    (
        --SECOND QUERY
        SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 T2 
        WHERE --CONDITIONS MET
            t.user_id = t2.id_user AND
            T.ID_TIP = T2.ID_TIP AND
            T.ID <> t2.ID AND 
            (T2.BEG BETWEEN T.BEG AND T.END)
            OR T2.BEG = T.END
    )

)
UPDATE CTE SET STAT=0, END = (T2.END - 1) --HERE IS WHERE I GET THE: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
WHERE ORDER> 1
GO
```

How could I call the non-linked variables?

*Code shortened because lenght

Comment: You can't access the subquery from outside. What is the `CONDITIONS MET`? You need to join the tables to get this information.

Comment: You need to expose the `END` column in the CTE results in order to use the value in the `WHERE` clause. Consequently, you'll need to use a join or scalar subquery instead of `EXISTS` and add the `END` column to the result. Alternatively. move the condition to the CTE.

Comment: @Rango The conditions are if users_id match, type_id match and record_id are different and dates are different.

Comment: The update statement is invalid. There is no reference to table T2 exposed by the CTE. The only columns that can be referenced are the columns from TABLE 1.

Comment: @Kurox: what if multiple rows from `Table2` match this condition? What `T2.End` you want to use to update `Table1`? The logic isn't clear at all.

Comment: @Rango I need to update older records against the new ones, these are stored all in one table.

Answer (score 1):

How about just doing a `JOIN`?

```
WITH toupdate AS (
      SELECT . . . ,
             ? as order
      FROM table1
     )
UPDATE T
    SET STAT = 0,
        END = (T2.END - 1)
    FROM T JOIN
         table2 T2 
         ON . . . <conditions here>
WHERE T.ORDER > 1;
```

Depending on what your conditions are in the subquery, you might still need the `EXISTS` clause as well.

Comment: `ORDER` comes from the CTE, i assume from `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION By...`

Comment: @Rango . . . According to the syntax provided, there is no `ROW_NUMBER()` in the subquery, only columns from `table1`.  Of course, a CTE could be used to define such a column if that is really needed, but it is definitely not part of the question.

Comment: he left out some relevant things, read his comment: _FIRST QUERY, ORDER AND PARTITION AS ORDER_

Comment: The order column is generated with row_number() and `partition by` wich sets another criteria outside my subquery, I don't think I can do that with a `JOIN`. I will put the entire first query, check the edit please.